# User registration via OOP and Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, oop

I am building a registration page for adding users updating their details and as well as  logging them in. I am using OOP style to do this. I was following a screen-cast but decided to go all the way.
The problem I am having is that I cannot register any user and I am not sure of why its not adding them to the database. Here is my code:

**DATABASE.PHP**

```
<?php
equire 'includes/config.php';
class Database {
    private $conn;
    function __construct() {
        $this->conn = new mysqli(DB_SERVER,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD,DB_NAME) or die(mysqli_error()) ;
    }
function addUser() {
        $query = 
            "INSERT INTO users VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

        if ($stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query)) {
            $stmt->bind_param('sssssss');
            $stmt->execute();
        }

    }
```

On my Ste users class I have the following:

**SITE_USERS.PHP**

```
require 'Database.php';

class siteRegisters {
function register_users($data) {
        $mysql = new Database();
        $ensure_registration = $mysql->addUser($data);

        if ($ensure_registration) {
            $_SESSION['status'] = 'authorised';
            header("location: admin.php");
        }else return "You could not be registered!";
    }
```

everytime I try to ad a new user I always get the error of "You could not be registered!"
My form looks like this:

```
session_start();
require_once 'classes/siteUsers.php';
$registeres = new siteRegisters();
if ($_POST && 
   !empty($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['lastname']) && 
   !empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password']) &&
   !empty($_POST['company']) &&  !empty($_POST['email']) &&
   !empty($_POST['phone'])
){
$response = $registeres->register_users($data);
   }
?>
    <form action="" method="post" />
    <fieldset>
  <?php
     if (isset($response)) echo "<h4 class'alert'>". $response ."</h4>";
 ?>
   <dl>
   <dt><label for="name">Name:</label></dt>
   <dd><input type="text" name="name" size="32"  title="Please fill in your Name" /></dd>

  //And so on
```

Any Helpful ideas? Please ? I

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = sprintf(
    "INSERT INTO users VALUES('',%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)",
    $data['name'], $data['lastname'],
    $data['username'], $data['password'],
    $data['company'], $data['email'],
    $data['phone']
);
```

Why do you have the `sprintf` here when you already have bound parameters (the *right* way to do it) later? Take it out.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO users VALUES('', ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
```

---

Next, you're passing the undefined variable `$data` to `$registeres->register_users()`. Try something like:

```
if(!empty($_POST['name'])     && !empty($_POST['lastname']) && 
   !empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password']) &&
   !empty($_POST['company'])  && !empty($_POST['email'])    &&
   !empty($_POST['phone'])
) {
    $response = $registeres->register_users($_POST);
}
```

Comment: I just tried doing your suggestion now and i still cannot register anyone. shoudn't I use function addUser($name,$lastneme ...) as vaules to be accepted ? I adjusted my database according see Question

Comment: @Anele: Now `addUser` has no `$data` parameter. Add that.

Answer (score 0):

You sould use ? for params, is what bind_params expect.

You don't need that fprintf,  ... what you are doing is concatenating the strings of the data from the user with the SQL.  So wen bind_param is executed, stuff like the email is already on the SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `register_users()` with `$data` but at this point `$data` does not exist:

```
$registeres = new siteRegisters();
if ($_POST && 
   !empty($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['lastname']) && 
   !empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password']) &&
   !empty($_POST['company']) &&  !empty($_POST['email']) &&
   !empty($_POST['phone'])
){
$response = $registeres->register_users($data);
   }
```

It looks like you want to pass the `$_POST` array instead like

```
$response = $registeres->register_users($_POST);
```